# problem occurs when Installing Kinect Demos for DiamondBack

Tags: ros, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

my system is ubuntu10.04 (32bit) ,installed with ROS( diamondback) and [openni_kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect).

i want to use the [mit kinect demo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos#General_Installation),then i fellow the guide from http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/dback

**1. BUT in step 6 ,i get a WARNING as follows:**

```
 WARNING: Skipped command line arguments: ['ni'] because they could not be resolved to a stack name or a package name.
```

**2. again i get a ERROR in step 7,**

```
[ rosmake ] All 22 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package skeletal_tracker
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests skeletal_tracker
  [rospack] couldn't find dependency [mapping_msgs] of [skeletal_tracker]
  [rospack] missing dependency
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'skeletal_tracker'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
    Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:7 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
```

i am NOT a native english speaker,so i don't know is there anyone who can understand my problem ,and help me solve it.thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10960/problem-occurs-when-installing-kinect-demos-for-diamondback/) by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-08-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rospack] couldn't find dependency [mapping_msgs] of [skeletal_tracker]
THE problem is it lacks mapping_msgs package !!

solution :

1.just download mapping_msgs(http://www.ros.org/wiki/mapping_msgs),via :

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk/mapping_msgs
```

,and then :

```
rosmake mapping_msgs
```

2. when building mapping_msgs ,it throw problem that it lacks :
   [rospack] couldn't find dependency [geometric_shapes_msgs] of [mapping_msg

download geometric_shapes_msgs,and then rosmake it.all will be ok !!

enjoy it !!

---

Originally posted by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) with karma: 71 on 2011-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi emerson,

For error 1 (the **ni** package) - I just figured that Garratt hadn't updated the documentation to use the **'openni'** package instead (since the **'ni'** package has been deprecated).

For error 2,
I encountered the same errors as you did which got me started to looking for the cause. I figured that it must have been possible to compile and run the demos in the past, which meant that something changed between then and now.

After sleuthing through the svn change logs of skeletal_tracker and mapping_msgs packages, I found this change (revision 51960 in the motion_planning_common/unstable stack) which occurred last June 24, 2011 made by gjones (who I suppose is a committer to the project) where he basically deleted all the packages leaving an empty shell in the unstable tag (this may have to do with releasing a new version 0.4 of the motion_planning_common stack) so I looked for a suitable replacement by using an older release (0.3.6).

I modified the file kinect_demos.rosinstall (see step 4 of the [installation instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos/dback)) and reran the steps 5 and up... this will include deleting the previous motion_planning_common stack so that the older 0.3.6 version can be downloaded.

I was able to build the packages without any error, but I haven't been able to run it yet as I currently don't have access to my kinect  hardware. I'll update this post once I get this new build tested.

Btw, below is the patch file for the change (I would have attached the patch file but I need to have at least a karma of 20 to be able to do that :()

```
===========================================
--- kinect_demos.rosinstall 2011-04-04 22:06:04.000000000 +0800
+++ kinect_demos-modified.rosinstall    2011-08-22 23:39:59.544413428 +0800
@@ -8,5 +8,5 @@
     uri: https://svn.csail.mit.edu/mit-ros-pkg/branches/sandbox
     local-name: mit-ros-pkg-experimental
 - svn:
-    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/tags/unstable/
+    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/tags/motion_planning_common-0.3.6/
     local-name: motion_planning_common
===============================================
```

To apply the patch, create a patch file containing the contents (don't include the dashes)
above and then run the command (assuming your patch file's name is kinect_demos.rosinstall.patch):

```
patch -p0 kinect_demos.rosinstall < kinect_demos.rosinstall.patch
```

I hope this solves your problem. Give me some feedback if this works for you.
I also hope the committers do a better job in making changes that break existing packages.

Best regards,

Butch

---

Originally posted by [butchland](https://answers.ros.org/users/976/butchland/) with karma: 41 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) on 2011-09-19**:
butchland ,ths for you help ! you are a kindly guy.i try your solution ,but it works no help.thank you all the same!!